# Why won't my main window center properly on the screen?

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to center my main window on my screen however neither of the two common ways are working. They both put it way too low and a little off center width wise. Here is what I have tried:

#### Way One:

```
screen = QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
x = int((screen.width() - self.width()) / 2)
y = int((screen.height() - self.height()) / 2)
self.move(x, y)
```

#### Way Two:

```
self.setGeometry(QStyle.alignedRect(Qt.LeftToRight, Qt.AlignCenter, self.size(),
                                            QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry()))
```

Note that right before doing this I set the width and height like this:

```
screen = QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
        ww = int(screen.width() / 1.5)
        wh = int(screen.height() / 2)

        self.resize(ww, wh)
```

Comment: Have you verified the values after calculation? I.e. are they correct and `move()` or `setGeometry()` are not using them as you expect?

Comment: Have you tried printing out the returned screen rect, the window dimensions and the final window position that you are computing? Perhaps that will give you some hint as to why it's not working. 

The same code works fine on my machine (way 1) so my best guess is that either your are running multiple monitors at different resolutions (calling screenGeometry() returns the geometry for the primary monitor), or you have some rogue piece of code resizing or moving your window after you run your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are moving the topLeft of your widget to the screen center that's why it is not centered. You should take into account the size of your widget.

```
x = QApplication().desktop().screenGeometry().center().x()
y = QApplication().desktop().screenGeometry().center().y()
self.move(x - self.geometry().width()/2, y - self.geometry().height()/2)
```

**Edit :**

this works if self is the mainWindow. If it is a widget with a parent, move will move(x,y) will move your widget relatively to its parent. you should translate the coordinates below (global coordinates) to Parent coordinates, using :

```
QPoint QWidget.mapFromGlobal (self, QPoint)
```

Comment: That moved the window into the bottom left corner

Comment: did you also change X and Y in the way i did?

Comment: Yes, I basically copied and pasted

Comment: is self a widget or the mainwindow ? because if self is a widget, move, will move it relatively to its parent widget. you should use mapFromGlobal to translate your global coordinates to parent widget coordinate. i edited the post.

Comment: I thought it was a mainwindow although my basic structure is that I have a ui.py file generated from Qt designer and then another class which inherits the generated class and this is where I do the changes. I then have another class that inherits this and main window. So at this point it wouldn't be a main window? Sorry that is very convoluted and not a good way of doing it, I know. Although moving the inheritance of main window does not solve the problem

Comment: the use of "QPoint QWidget.mapFromGlobal (self, QPoint)" didn't solve your problem? QPoint are the coordinates we calculate before.

Comment: No my window is a main window. Could this problem be a result of the resize before hand not working as the values I choose are smaller than what the layout can allow? i.e my window has a minimum size and when I resize it it may have to 'bounce' to those bounds

Comment: Possible. Try moving the move code after you show your window and see what happens.

Comment: This answer is wrong. His original formula listed for 'way one' is correct. Double check the parentheses and you will see.

Comment: It is not wrong, since the center coordinates are (screen.width()/2, screen.height()/2). So both ways should work and give the same result. And i don't see how it can be wrong if it works!

Comment: What actually worked for me was moving where I show my window. I think I still use my preferred method of centering the screen which is the second on in my initial question.